PVC to copper domestic water repair
Hi I need to repair the PVC to copper connection here due to split in female threaded PVC. Is it against code to use Teflon taped fittings underground? I was thinking maybe raise vertical PVC above ground to connect to copper. On the other hand copper is more resistant to dings from garden tools etc. there's probably a few variations for this repair. Appreciate comments

You do not show the whole thing, but the section that is shown, seems to be available to movement of side to side.  Mounting/clamping the pipe to the wall might help.
